Visualforce component not triggering getters
I have a task to create a email template which uses a visualforce component with some tables of data on Leads. The email did not show the tables properly so I put the VF component on a VF page to debug it. I am beginning to feel stuck on this issue so I'd love some pointers.
<apex:component controller="findListForEscalete" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="status" type="String" assignTo="{!statusValue}" description="Status of the lead"/>
    <apex:attribute name="threshold" type="String" assignTo="{!thresholdValue}" description="Minimum duration in days" />
    <apex:attribute name="thresholdmax" type="String" assignTo="{!thresholdValueMax}" description="Maximum duration in days" />
    <apex:attribute name="usern" type="String" assignTo="{!userName}" description="User ID" />
    <apex:attribute name="colorThreshold" type="String" assignTo="{!colorThresholdVal}" description="Threshold for color coding" />
    <apex:attribute name="PublicGroupOrQueue" type="String" assignTo="{!pg_or_queue}" description="Public group or queue" />

    <p> Duration between {!thresholdValue} - {!thresholdValueMax} Days </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    
    <!-- Hot Leads Table -->
    <h3>Hot Leads</h3>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Lead Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Duration<br/>in Days</th>
            <th>Hot Lead</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat var="item" value="{!hotLeads}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{!item.esLink}">{!item.esName}</a></td>
                <td>{!item.esStatus}</td>
                <td class="{!item.esvalueClass}">{!item.esStageDuration}</td>
                <td>{!item.esHotLead}</td>
                <td>{!item.esOwnerName}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>

    <br />
    <br />

    <!-- Cold Leads Table -->
    <h3>Cold Leads</h3>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Lead Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Duration<br/>in Days</th>
            <th>Hot Lead</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat var="item" value="{!coldLeads}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{!item.esLink}">{!item.esName}</a></td>
                <td>{!item.esStatus}</td>
                <td class="{!item.esvalueClass}">{!item.esStageDuration}</td>
                <td>{!item.esHotLead}</td>
                <td>{!item.esOwnerName}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:component>

And here is the controller
public class findListForEscalete {

    public String statusValue { get; set; }
    public String thresholdValue { get; set; }
    public String thresholdValueMax { get; set; }
    public String userName { get; set; }
    public String pg_or_queue { get; set; }
    public String colorThresholdVal { get; set; }
    public List<item> hotLeads { get; set; }
    public List<item> coldLeads { get; set; }
    

    public findListForEscalete() {
        System.debug('Called from find Escalate');
        hotLeads = new List<item>();
        coldLeads = new List<item>();
    }

    public List<item> getHotLeads() {
        System.debug('called from hot leads');
        populateLeads();
        return hotLeads;
    }

    public List<item> getColdLeads() {
        populateLeads();
        return coldLeads;
    }

    public void populateLeads() {


        system.debug('Status            -->' + statusValue);
        system.debug('User name         -->' + this.userName);
        system.debug('thresholdValue    -->' + this.thresholdValue);
        system.debug('thresholdValueMax -->' + this.thresholdValueMax);
        system.debug('Public group or queue -->' + this.pg_or_queue);

        List<LeadEscalation.escalationItem> result = new List<LeadEscalation.escalationItem>();
        Integer val = this.thresholdValue != null ? Integer.valueOf(this.thresholdValue) : 1;
        Integer valMax = this.thresholdValueMax != null ? Integer.valueOf(this.thresholdValueMax) : 7;
        this.statusValue = 'Status';
        this.userName = this.userName != null ? this.userName : UserInfo.getUserId();

        result = LeadEscalation.getEscelationList(this.statusValue, val, valMax, this.userName, 'queue', 'Status');

    }

    public class item {
        public String esId { get; set; }
        public String esLeadId { get; set; }
        public String esStatus { get; set; }
        public String esName { get; set; }
        public Datetime esStageDate { get; set; }
        public Integer esStageDuration { get; set; }
        public String esLink { get; set; }
        public String esOwnerName { get; set; }
        public String esvalueClass { get; set; }
        public Boolean esHotLead { get; set; }
    }
}

I've excluded the rest of the code since it works more on getting the correct data itself. My thought process was that when the component is called, the 2 getter methods are being and thus data is filled in the 2 lists. Then I can display the tables with the data from these 2 lists. However nothing is getting called.
This is how I called the component on the page
<apex:page >
    <c:leadEscalationEmail status="Status" threshold="0" thresholdmax="999" colorThreshold="150" usern="{!$User.Id}" PublicGroupOrQueue="queue"/>
</apex:page>

Any help is appreciated

When you have both a variable with a getter and setter, plus method(s) that starts with get and/or set, the variable takes priority.
For example:
    public List<item> coldLeads { get; set; }

Takes priority over:
    public List<item> getColdLeads() {
        populateLeads();
        return coldLeads;
    }

Further, you never actually added any values to your lists, so they are empty.
You don't really need this complicated of a setup, as you can always just populate the leads during the constructor. The extra methods aren't necessary here.

Thank you for the explanation. Now it works!
